# Cyclic tile template Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I am trying to create cyclic tile template using this code

```
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);

var tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150Image);

var tileImage = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName(“image”)[0] as XmlElement;
tileImage.SetAttribute(“src”, “ms-appx:///Assets/image1.jpg”);
var tileNotification = new TileNotification(tileXml);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileNotification);

tileImage.SetAttribute(“src”, “ms-appx:///Assets/image2.jpg”);
tileNotification = new TileNotification(tileXml);
tileNotification.Tag = “myTag”;
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileNotification);
```

But the tiles are not cyclic they are only flipping. How to make the above code to act as cyclic tile??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycle Tile template is old - for Windows Phone 8 or Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight. You can read about them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/JJ207036(v=VS.105).aspx). For Windows Phone 8.1 RT you can only use the new templates like TileSquare150x150Image that are all listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/hh761491.aspx). The new ones unfortunately don't have the nice 'Ken Burns' effect like the Cycle Tile template.