# How to show multiple images on a secondary tile in windows 10 uwp?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm trying to create a secondary tile, which shows pictures in rotation like in the photos app. I have tried something like this:

```
SecondaryTile tile = GenerateSecondaryTile("NewTile", "SecondaryTile");
await tile.RequestCreateAsync();
var ImageUrl = selectedFileList.ElementAt(0).Path;
string tileXmlString =
"<tile>"
+ "<visual>"
+ "<binding template='TileSmall'>"
+ "<image  src='" + selectedFileList.ElementAt(0).Path + "' alt='image'/>"
+ "<image  src='" + selectedFileList.ElementAt(1).Path + "' alt='image'/>"
+ "<image  src='" + selectedFileList.ElementAt(2).Path + "' alt='image'/>"
+ "<image  src='" + selectedFileList.ElementAt(3).Path + "' alt='image'/>"
+ "<image src='" + selectedFileList.ElementAt(4).Path + "' alt='image'/>"
+ "</binding>"
+ "</visual>"
+ "</tile>";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(tileXmlString);
TileNotification notifyTile = new TileNotification(xmlDoc);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile(tile.TileId).Update(notifyTile);
```

I have tried setting the type as both background and peek but it doesn't give the required result. And also I would not like to use a background task as my app already uses one and I wouldn't want to increase the overhead which might cause the task to fail entirely. I wouldn't mind if the images were limited to 5 like earlier in Windows phone 8.1.

For reference : check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXnghpGdI2c&feature=youtu.be) out : Skip to 0:30

Answer (score 1):

This is for Primary Tile, but it should work the same way. Make your own XML Template, then reference your image. Enable notification queue then update the Tile with the TileNotification. Do this up to five times to put five images on the Live Tile stack.

```
var myStorageFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("LiveTileTemplate.xml");
string liveTileTemplate = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(myStorageFile);
liveTileTemplate = liveTileTemplate.Replace("squareImageSource", FilePathFullPrefix + GetFilePathSquareTile(imageID));

TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(new TileNotification(mergedXML));
```

Comment: Okay this works as expected! A small doubt though if you've noticed the live tile of photos app it shows a moving image but doesn't happen in this case?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the images don't have the 'Ken Burns' effect anymore. They were only supported by the Cyclic Template, which was on Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight. I've answered a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766245/cyclic-tile-template-windows-phone-8-1/32419363#32419363

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate, it was a pretty cool effect! Thanks for your help!